# nyroModal Window on flash background

Tags: flash, google-chrome, nyromodal

I've got a Flex App running at 100% width and 100% height. The embed code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fVars = {};
    fVars.wmode = "transparent"; //also tried "opaque"
    swfobject.embedSWF("/swf/app.swf", "app", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", fVars);
</script>
<div class="app"></div>
```

I've also got the nyroModal call, which is essentially

```
$.nyroModalManual({
    url: urlPath,
    wrap: {},
    closeButton: ""
});
```

The modal window I am trying to open in this case is a div with some text and another flash embed, which works.

I've also got the app div's z-index to 0.

In Firefox this looks fine, everything works. In Chrome however, nyroModal's fade-in/transparent overlay does not show up, and only the second swf is visible overtop the background flash.

Am I missing anything here? Is this a known issue with Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the wmode going into the fVars instead of the params. Oops!